# SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 7

Tags: node.js, json, post, syntax-error, json-deserialization

I am trying to make a `POST` request to `/register`

```
POST http://localhost:4001/register
content-type: application/json

{
    first_name: "Emmanuel",
    last_name: "Jirigho",
    email: "emma@gmail.com",
    password: "12345"
}
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 7
> at JSON.parse

Answer (score 2):

Key in json must have `"`.

```json
{ 
  "first_name": "Emmanuel",
  "last_name": "Jirigho",
  "email": "emma@gmail.com",
  "password": "12345"
}
```